# Belkin USB 3.0 Ethernet not Recognized

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I'm new to Linux. I have a Lenovo G51 AMD A8 laptop that the onboard Ethernet has gone out and the wifi is unstable at best. I bought a Belkin USB 3.0 Ethernet adapter with extra USB 3.0 ports. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS recognizes the extra USB ports, but not the Ethernet connection. `ifconfig` doesn't see it and I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated, as I have to use Windows for my podcasts until I can get a stable connection with Ubuntu.

This is what I get from running `lsusb` with the Ethernet adapter plugged in. It looks like Ubuntu sees the adapter but doesn't know what to do with it.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174f:1158 Syntek 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 08bb:2902 Texas Instruments PCM2902 Audio Codec
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0c45:7702 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 007: ID 050d:0128 Belkin Components 
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I thought I would wait and see if the problem resolved with the release of 17.04. As you can see from above, the answer is "No".

Comment: @DavidAdkins Is the system running 17.04 now?

Comment: It is as of last night. Clean install. That is what lsusb showed me in 17.04.

Comment: Is it possible that the AX88179 drivers haven't been added to the Linux kernel yet?